# TypeSafe Scala IDE (Eclipse) doesn't show any Scala projects

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide

I'm running Mac Os 10.5.8, with java sdk 1.5.0_30. I've downloaded and installed the sbt package, and have verified that it is running properly. Finally, I've downloaded the Mac OS Cocoa 32-bit version of the Typesafe IDE for Scala 2.10.1, and have installed it.

The problem is that although Eclipse seems to recognize that it's set up to use Scala (the header of the default window starts with 'Resource - Scala IDE...'), no Scala projects or worksheets are available from anywhere - "New" only shows "Project", not "Scala Project", "New->Other" doesn't show any Scala wizards, right-clicking on an imported file from a Scala project doesn't show the possibility of creating a Scala worksheet, etc.

#### Additional information:

1. This is Indigo
2. There is no Scala menu between Run and Window
3. The left side menu says "Project Explorer"
4. About>Installation Details> Features includes the Scala plugin

#### Configuration Details (truncated):

```
*** Date: Saturday, April 6, 2013 9:00:43 AM Eastern Daylight Time

*** Platform Details:

*** System properties:
awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true
awt.toolkit=apple.awt.CToolkit
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=3.0.0-vfinal-20130326-1146-Typesafe
eclipse.commands=-os
macosx
-ws
cocoa
-arch
ppc
-showsplash
-launcher
/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
-name
Eclipse
--launcher.library
/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504/eclipse_1408.so
-startup
/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-keyring
/Users/me/.eclipse_keyring
-showlocation
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
eclipse.home.location=file:/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/
eclipse.launcher=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
eclipse.p2.profile=SDKProfile
eclipse.product=org.scala-ide.sdk.product
eclipse.startTime=1365252840252
eclipse.vm=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
eclipse.vmargs=-Xmx1048m
-Xms100m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Djava.class.path=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=MacRoman
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=/
gopherProxySet=false
java.awt.graphicsenv=apple.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=apple.awt.CPrinterJob
java.class.path=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
java.class.version=49.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext
java.home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/Fi/FiG8O39A2Ra7AE+1YwLaJ++++TI/-Tmp-/
java.library.path=.:/Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition
java.runtime.version=1.5.0_30-b03-389-9M3425
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.5
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
java.vendor.url=http://www.apple.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.apple.com/
java.version=1.5.0_30
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.vendor=Apple Inc.
java.vm.version=1.5.0_30-161
line.separator=

mrj.build=9M3425
mrj.version=1050.1.5.0_30-389
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.2.v201202080800/splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts=
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5
org.osgi.framework.language=en
org.osgi.framework.os.name=MacOSX
org.osgi.framework.os.version=10.5.8
org.osgi.framework.processor=PowerPC
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=javax.accessibility,javax.activity,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.interfaces,javax.crypto.spec,javax.imageio,javax.imageio.event,javax.imageio.metadata,javax.imageio.plugins.bmp,javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,javax.imageio.spi,javax.imageio.stream,javax.management,javax.management.loading,javax.management.modelmbean,javax.management.monitor,javax.management.openmbean,javax.management.relation,javax.management.remote,javax.management.remote.rmi,javax.management.timer,javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.event,javax.naming.ldap,javax.naming.spi,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,javax.print,javax.print.attribute,javax.print.attribute.standard,javax.print.event,javax.rmi,javax.rmi.CORBA,javax.rmi.ssl,javax.security.auth,javax.security.auth.callback,javax.security.auth.kerberos,javax.security.auth.login,javax.security.auth.spi,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.security.cert,javax.security.sasl,javax.sound.midi,javax.sound.midi.spi,javax.sound.sampled,javax.sound.sampled.spi,javax.sql,javax.sql.rowset,javax.sql.rowset.serial,javax.sql.rowset.spi,javax.swing,javax.swing.border,javax.swing.colorchooser,javax.swing.event,javax.swing.filechooser,javax.swing.plaf,javax.swing.plaf.basic,javax.swing.plaf.metal,javax.swing.plaf.multi,javax.swing.plaf.synth,javax.swing.table,javax.swing.text,javax.swing.text.html,javax.swing.text.html.parser,javax.swing.text.rtf,javax.swing.tree,javax.swing.undo,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.xa,javax.xml,javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.sax,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xml.validation,javax.xml.xpath,org.ietf.jgss,org.omg.CORBA,org.omg.CORBA_2_3,org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable,org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage,org.omg.CORBA.portable,org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage,org.omg.CosNaming,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage,org.omg.Dynamic,org.omg.DynamicAny,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.IOP,org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage,org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage,org.omg.Messaging,org.omg.PortableInterceptor,org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage,org.omg.PortableServer,org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.portable,org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage,org.omg.SendingContext,org.omg.stub.java.rmi,org.w3c.dom,org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,org.w3c.dom.css,org.w3c.dom.events,org.w3c.dom.html,org.w3c.dom.ls,org.w3c.dom.ranges,org.w3c.dom.stylesheets,org.w3c.dom.traversal,org.w3c.dom.views ,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.ext,org.xml.sax.helpers
org.osgi.framework.uuid=f015af0e-b99e-0012-1997-8799bf6d8071
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.6.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=ppc
os.name=Mac OS X
os.version=10.5.8
osgi.arch=ppc
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20120427-0800.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar@1:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.bundlestore=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles
osgi.configuration.area=file:/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/configuration/
osgi.framework=file:/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20120427-0800.jar
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.version=3.7.2.v20120110-1415
osgi.frameworkClassPath=., file:/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20120427-0800.jar
osgi.install.area=file:/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/
osgi.instance.area=file:/Users/me/Scala class/
osgi.logfile=/Users/me/Scala class/.metadata/.log
osgi.manifest.cache=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/manifests
osgi.nl=en_US
osgi.os=macosx
osgi.splashLocation=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.2.v201202080800/splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.syspath=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/plugins
osgi.tracefile=/Users/me/Scala class/.metadata/trace.log
osgi.ws=cocoa
path.separator=:
sun.arch.data.model=32
sun.boot.class.path=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jsfd.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/laf.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/sunrsasign.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/jce.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/charsets.jar
sun.boot.library.path=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Libraries
sun.cpu.endian=big
sun.cpu.isalist=
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
sun.jnu.encoding=MacRoman
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
user.country=US
user.dir=/Users/me/Downloads/eclipse - Scala/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
user.home=/Users/me
user.language=en
user.name=me
user.timezone=America/New_York

*** Features:
org.eclipse.cvs (1.3.100.v20110520-0800-7B78FHl9VF7BD7KBM4GP9C) "Eclipse CVS Client"
org.eclipse.help (1.3.0.v20110530-0844-7i7uFFmFFl8nvqbDpEqTvx) "Help System Base"
org.eclipse.jdt (3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1) "Eclipse Java Development Tools"
org.eclipse.m2e.feature (1.3.1.20130219-1424) "Maven Integration for Eclipse"
org.eclipse.pde (3.7.2.v20120120-1420-7b7rFUOFEx2Xnqafnpz0E--0) "PDE"
org.eclipse.platform (3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q) "Eclipse Platform"
org.eclipse.rcp (3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272) "Eclipse RCP"
org.scala-ide.sdk.feature (3.0.0.201303261047) "Scala Plugin"
```

Comment: Which version of eclipse have you downloaded? Indigo (3.7) or Juno(4.2) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have access to Mac OS 10.5.x, so I can't directly reproduce your setup. However, on 10.7, the **32-bit** Cocoa version worked as expected. To troubleshoot this, we need a few more data points:

- Do you see a *Scala* menu (between *Run* and *Window*)?
- Is the left side panel called *Package Explorer*?
- Can you post the installation details (`Eclipse->About Scala IDE -> Installation Details/Configuration`.

Comment: posted what I could, subject to the 30K char limit. Let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched to the Scala perspective?

Comment: No Scala perspective is available.

Answer (score 0):

I got one same problem : it is probably that the scala plugins are not loaded.

To check it, Go to menu Help -> About, clic on Installation Detail, tab named Installed Software : if it is here and not in features Tab then uninstall all scala related soft in the Installation detail tab (there is an uninstall button at the bottom).
Then reinstall it by configuring a new update site in the installation software dialog box (Menu Help -> install new software)

Comment: Installed Software includes JDT Weaving for Scala, Scala Worksheet, etc. Features includes the Scala Plugin.